# Is it advisible to prefix a custom directive with 'ng' in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a small directive in AngularJS to display the user info, Here is the code which I have written to accomplish,

```
angular.module('app').directive('userProfile', function(){
    return {
      templateUrl: "userProfile.html",
      restrict: 'E',
    }
});
```

And I'm including this directive in my `index.html` as,

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <user-profile><user-profile>
  </body>
```

And if I want to use the `ng-` prefix to maintain some uniform structure across project, right now I've tried changing the `.directive('userProfile'` declaration to `.directive('ngUserProfile'` which is actually working.

However I would like to know whether it is recommended to mimic the `ng-` behavior and if so, is there any best practice available which I can make use of?

Please help!.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: (**Its bad practice**) don't use `ng-` prefix for custom directives because angular uses `ng-` convention, It may lead to conflict with angular directive in future. Best practice to have you own prefix like `ms-user-profile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixing with ng is **NOT** a good idea.

The ng module is loaded by default when an AngularJS application is started. The module itself contains the essential components for an AngularJS application to function.

It is highly recommended not to have ng prefix to custom components (directives/filters) which we develop since it should not collide with any of the angular components in future.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular"
`ng-` prefix is predefine angular prefix for directive.
So if you are looking for custom directive, you can use anything in prefix as you want.

```
.directive("myDir", function() { 
  // logic
})
```

The prefix `ng` stands for "Angular;" all of the built-in directives that ship with Angular use that prefix.
Similarly, it is recommended that you do not use the `ng` prefix on your own directives in order to avoid possible name collisions in future versions of Angular.

**Go through this** [**link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use ng prefix**.

This is the naming standard of AngularJS for its directives, it is better not to use it in order not to confuse with customs directives.

Answer (score 0):

David R,

I recommend you to read the style guide on AngularJS by John Papa

[Here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#user-content-provide-a-unique-directive-prefix) is a note on providing prefix for custom directives